# How to add description to OpenAPI schema using FastApi Dependencies

Tags: python, swagger, openapi, fastapi

Is there a way to add field description to FastAPI swagger schema if I use dependency system?

I see no place to add descriptions in simple example from [FastAPI docs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/#declare-the-dependency-in-the-dependant)

```py
async def common_parameters(q: str = None, skip: int = 0, limit: int = 100):
    return {"q": q, "skip": skip, "limit": limit}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can also use this

```
@app.get("/dummy")
async def dummy(q: Optional[str] = Query(None, )):
    """
     This is my description of the API endpoint
    """
    pass
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add description using `Query` or `Body` depends on your use case.

```py
from typing import Optional

from fastapi import FastAPI, Query

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/dummy")
async def dummy(q: Optional[str] = Query(None, description="My description")):
    ...
```

You can add even more metadata, see the [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params-str-validations/#declare-more-metadata).